# How to hide mat-tooltip when using RouteReuseStrategy

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I am trying to implement RouteReuseStrategy on our Angular 6 application.  Recently I found that mat-tooltip are not getting hidden when we have tooltip on the button with routerLink using RouteReuseStrategy.

Is there any way to hide the tooltip before navigating to new route.

Here is the example stackblitz with the issue: https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-tooltip-routereuse

Comment: It is also posted in [github issues](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/11478#issuecomment-420164916)

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I had to do to close any overlay on button navigating:

```
window.onpopstate = function(event) {
  let overlay = document.getElementsByClassName('cdk-overlay-backdrop-showing')[0];
  overlay && overlay.click();
};
```

or in the AppComponent

```
constructor(location: PlatformLocation) {
  location.onPopState(() => {
  let overlay = document.getElementsByClassName('cdk-overlay-backdrop-showing')[0] as HTMLElement;
  overlay && overlay.click();
});
```